# How to install Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm new to Linux and am trying out Elementary. I need to install Google Chrome and do not see it in the app store, but I downloaded it directly from the Google site. However, I don't understand what I need to do with the file that downloaded. It contains some .tar.gz files and a binary file, how do I install an app from that?

Comment: Thank the gods for Chrome, the tiny stock stock browser scroll bar width was putting me within 5 minutes of deleting this distro.

Answer (score 7):

the official Google Chrome app can be downloaded from Google
Just download the Deb package and then on a terminal browse to the folder where the deb package is and run:

```
sudo dpkg --install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Link to deb package:

`https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/thankyou.html?platform=linux&installdataindex=defaultbrowser`

Comment: IMO https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7937/5722 is better as it only involves learning the `apt` command, which can be used in the future for packages with dependencies - a little more user-friendly I think.

Comment: I get some dependency issue while doing so, have you tried it on your's ?

Comment: @ShankarRegmi have you tried running `sudo apt -f install` ?

Comment: I did this, and it removed the Google Chrome package. I then realized that my apt cache was not up to date (due to various reasons, mostly network connectivity issues and the short amount of time since I started the machine - apt automatic refresh usually happens at night). After running `sudo apt update` it managed to resolve the dependencies and complete the installation.

Comment: I don't understand why people point to dpkg, while there is apt? And for unexperienced users I would always recommend installing GDebi Package Installer from the AppCenter if they want to install .deb files. This way they don't even need to open a Terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a search engine like google to anwser that question. Chromium is like the Open-Source version of Google Chrome, and it's works equal.

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

If you really want to install Google Chrome, in the [Google Chrome's official page](https://www.google.es/chrome/) you can to download the Ubuntu's .deb file for 64 bits, and install via console with apt. But you can to download and install with the next command:

```
curl -O https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Does Chromium support the DRM extensions needed for things like Netflix etc.?

Comment: chromium supports widevine (which is what Netflix uses) but it requires an additional relatively trivial installation (see here for example how its done in Arch: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/chromium#Widevine_Content_Decryption_Module_plugin ). For my needs, the main reason to use Google's Flash support, which can also be enabled in Chromium but its a much more involved process.

Comment: Why not point out Chromium can also easily be installed from the AppCenter? Not all people like using the Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Google Chrome you can install the base Chromium browser easily:

Via the App Center. Open App Center, type 'Chrom' in the search bar (upper right of App Center window), select Chromium in the list and click Install.

Comment: The question specifically asks how to install Google Chrome, not Chromium. You might want to specify in your answer that Chromium and Chrome are not the same, and perhaps highlight some of the differences.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I did not realize they were different. I update my post.

Answer (score 0):

cd to the directory the .deb is in.
`sudo dpkg -i {installer.deb}`
It will probably fail because of missing dependencies then do:
`sudo apt -f install`
To install the missing dependencies.

Good luck.

Comment: FYI, this can be done in one step using `apt install ./installer.deb`, inculding dependency installation.